# Assign value to specific bit of BitVecExpr in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

Here is my verilog statement:

```
reg[2:0] a;            // Create register 'a' which is 3 bit.
assign a[1] = 1'b1;    // Assigning value to 1st bit of register 'a'.
```

I have to implement the statement above in Z3.
For the 1st line of the verilog statement using BitVecExpr:

```
BitVecExpr a = ctx.mkBVConst("a",3);
```

I am a facing problem while implementing 2nd line of verilog statement.
Does anyone know how to implement this in Z3?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Do you think we have direct solution to this problem in Z3.

Answer (score 1):

With Z3 you can't modify variables. In fact Z3 doesn't call this a variable, it's a constant.

You need to make a new constant that is related to the old constant. For example if you want to say `y = x + 1` this would be

```
var y = ctx.MkBVAdd(x, 1);
```

If you want to say `x = x + 1` you need to introduce a new name for the old and for the new `x`:

```
var x2 = ctx.MkBVAdd(x1, 1);
```

Comment: i understand what you meant to say, but my issue is i have multiple assignment for single constant. For eg:  assign a[1] = 1'b1;    assign a[0] = 1'b0;    assign a[3:2] = 2'b01;   and so on. I was thinking if there are any direct solution for this problem, like i can directly go and assign value to any specific bit in Z3. Do you think we can do that?

Comment: Assigning values does not make sense. You are asking Z3 to give you a model for a boolean formula. You can't "assign" to parts of a formula. Probably, what you need is something like `b = replacebits(ctx, a)` where `replacebits` stands for operations such as `MkExtract` or `MkConcat`.